# Force Eve to validate document inside custom route

Tags: eve, cerberus

In my python/eve REST API I have a custom route that does some non trivial processing. I'm receiving a POST request and after some processing I'll send this doc to database. But it would be nice if I could validate this doc using the same validation used by Eve. I know I can use cerberus directly but it does not handle things like `data_relation` which I have in my schema.

There is any way I can invoke the internal Eve validator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the default Validator (or your own subclass if you customised it). The following example snippet uses a database hook (documents are processed just before db insertion).

```
from eve.io.mongo import Validator
from flask import current_app

validator = Validator()

def on_insert(resource, documents):        
    schema = current_app.config['DOMAIN'][resource]['schema']
    for document in items:
        if not validator(document):
            print validator.errors


app = Eve()
app.on_insert += on_insert

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Now, this example would return errors on every single document since, at this stage, they include automatic fields such as `_created` and `_updated`, which are not included in the schema, but you get the idea (you could circumvent this issue by setting `allow_unknown` property for the validator instance).

Comment: Shame on me! I already have a custom validator with a few custom types defined in it and I did not thought in using it to solve my problem.... Thanks @NicolaIarocci, by the way: great job with Eve!